# Database PHPMYADMIn

Tags: database, phpmyadmin

I want to create a database with 5000 entries (coupons) and 6 columns for each entry. The first column entry is to be numbered from 1 to 5000. The second column in each entry is a unique 11 digit code. All other column entries are identical for every coupon.

If i create an entry in phpMyadmin, then copy it and change the first column entry to increment it by one for the new coupon, and add the new 11 digit code to the second column entry and save as new entry, it is faster than creating an entirely new entry from scratch, but it will still take ages to repeat this 5000 times.

I have each of the 5000 unique codes in a word file. Is there a way to duplicate one of my coupon code entries 5000 times incrementing the first column entry by 1 (ie from 1-5000), then uploading the 5000 unique 11 digit codes, and assign a unique 11 digit code to the second column of each of the 5000 entries?

Comment: Please [edit] your question title to something that actually describes the problem you're trying to solve or question you're asking. Merely repeating the tags in the title is useless to future readers here who are trying to find a solution to a similar problem and see this question in the search results. Your title should be actually meaningful and explain what you're asking here. Thanks.

Comment: You can either write a stored procedure and call it 5000 times which will insert the records, OR you can use the magic of spreadsheet to generate insert queries and execute those on the database.

Comment: Using a graphical tool to do batch jobs is always going to end in frustration. If you need to create 5000 records, write a script to do it; don't try to do it via a graphical tool like phpMyAdmin.

Answer (score 1):

Why not just turn your .word file into a .csv file and then upload it into your database using the "import" option? You could get all your coupons on the database,since I'm guessing you will be using them later on anyways?